# Get Progress of UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, progress

Is there a way to get the percentage of the page loaded from a `UIWebView`in Swift with from a standard `@IBOutlet`?

```
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!;
```

Comment: If your main objective is to show to the user that something is loading consider using a [UIActivityIndicatorView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/)

Comment: @DanielStorm I was hoping to get the percentage to display it to the user in a way that is not just a spinner, such as a UIProgressView. I have seen similar questions, but the answers just increment with time, not with how far the page has actually loaded.

Comment: Are you expecting the pages in your `UIWebView` to take longer than 10 seconds to load? http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/77123

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with a UIWebView, no; it isn't possible.

But, new in iOS 8, you can use WKWebView, which has an `estimatedProgress` property which you can observe using key-value observing and thus get updates as the progress of loading proceeds.